# How to stop a stream.write function in sounddevice

Tags: python, audio, python-sounddevice

Is it possible to stop a stream.write function before the buffer is consumed completely?
When I try to do so, the sound is stopped, but the stream.write function never returns.

This is a working example of how I want to use a small class to play pure tone sounds without blocking the main thread.

```
import time
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread

toneduration = 10
samplerate = 44100
frequency = 440
amplitude = 0.5

sd.default.device = 1
sd.default.samplerate = samplerate
sd.default.channels = 2

class Sound(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stream = sd.OutputStream()
        self.stream.start()

        vector1 = np.linspace(0, toneduration, toneduration * samplerate)
        vector2 = amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * vector1)
        vector3 = np.array([vector2, vector2])
        self.soundVector = np.ascontiguousarray(vector3.T, dtype=np.float32)

    def run(self):
        self.stream.write(self.soundVector)
        print('end')

sound = Sound()
sound.start()
time.sleep(3)
sound.stream.close()
```

I can play sounds of a given duration, but if I manually stop the stream using `stream.close()` the function doesn't return (the `print('end')` message is never displayed and the thread doesn't finish)

Do I have to use callback instead? In that case, how am I supposed to fill the buffer with a numpy array? I read the code examples in the documentation but I couldn’t figure it out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the simplest way would be to use the [play()](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.14/api.html#sounddevice.play) function, which per default starts playback in the background (using a callback function called from a separate thread created by the underlying PortAudio library).
You can then use the [stop()](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.14/api.html#sounddevice.stop) function to stop playback.

If you need something more complicated than a simple playback of a NumPy array, you can implement your own callback function.
As an example, you can look at the implementation of the `play()` function or at the [examples](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/tree/master/examples), e.g. [play_long_file.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/play_long_file.py).

As you mentioned, you can also use the so-called "blocking" API (using the [write()](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.14/api.html#sounddevice.Stream.write) method).

Either way, you would typically split your audio data into a series of blocks.
This way, you can arrange for the playback to be stopped after any one of the blocks. This is also what the `play()` function does internally.